# iTunes Connect Users won't load

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

So I really have 2 issues (obviously this question being one, but extra credit points if you can help with second).

The main one being, my iTunes Connect Users are not loading. It's just empty. I have like 20 internal testers that are usually loaded but for some reason this morning I don't see anyone. See screenshot: 
[image: iTunes Connect Users Not Loading]

What gives?

Also #2 (you do not have to answer to get answer checked, just seeing if anyone knows why this is happening): It appears that if you remove a user from your internal iTunes Connect Users and re-add them, they aren't able to download the app from test flight anymore. Anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So weird. Viewing in a new browser seemed to do the trick.

Also, if anyone is wondering, I was able to solve my #2 by the following:

- Re-add user to Test Flight group
- Have user GO ON DESKTOP (not mobile phone)
- Open Test Flight email
- Click 'View in Test Flight'
- Get the Redeem code from page
- Go to Test Flight app on phone, type in redeem code, and voila works like a charm

The bug seems to be when you remove a user from test flight, and then re-add them and they accept via phone.